# How do I render the same data to multiple views?

Tags: javascript, express, ejs

I'm working on a blog and I have a form where I fill out a title and a body of content. When I hit  submit the data is rendered and can be viewed in my `article_list` ejs form. What I'm trying to accomplish is getting that data and having it display on another page.

On my home page (`index.ejs`) I have a section called "Most Recent Article". I need the data sent from `article_list` to also be sent to `index` so my home page can display my most recent article.

`Article Schema`

```
const ArticleSchema = new Schema({
  title: { type: String, required: true },
  content: { type: String, required: true },
});
```

Here is the function that takes the data from my form and renders it to that page.

```
exports.article_list = function (req, res, next) {
  Article.find({}, "title author")
    .sort({ title: 1 })
    .populate("author")
    .exec(function (err, list_articles) {
      if (err) {
        return next(err);
      }
      res.render("article_list", {
        title: "Article List",
        article_list: list_articles,
      });
    });
};
```

When I click submit and view the list of articles, everything works as intended.

`index.ejs`

```
<div class="main__content-recent">
  <h2 class="main__tabs-title">Most Recent Article</h2>
  <p class="main__article-p">
    <%= article_list.content[-1] %>   (Read More...)</span>
  </p>
</div>
```

Because I can only render to one ejs file, the `article_list.content[-1]` is showing as undefined. I'm wondering if there is any way to render the same data twice to multiple ejs files or if not, what I should do.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the Schema to this :

```
const ArticleSchema = new Schema({
  title: { type: String, required: true },
  content: { type: String, required: true },
  createdAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
});
```

After this, in your article_list function, you can modify the query to this:y

```
exports.article_list = function (req, res, next) {
  Article.find({}, "title content createdAt")
    .sort({ createdAt: -1 })
    .limit(1)
    .exec(function (err, recent_article) {
      if (err) {
        return next(err);
      }
      res.render("article_list", {
        title: "Article List",
        article_list: recent_article,
      });
    });
};
```

You can modify the index function to fetch the most recent article separately and render it in the `index.ejs` file:

```
exports.index = function (req, res) {
  Article.find({}, "title content createdAt")
    .sort({ createdAt: -1 })
    .limit(1)
    .exec(function (err, recent_article) {
      if (err) {
        return next(err);
      }
      res.render("index", {
        title: "Home",
        recent_article: recent_article,
      });
    });
};
```

after this you can access `recent_article[0].content` in the html

```
<div class="main__content-recent">
  <h2 class="main__tabs-title">Most Recent Article</h2>
  <p class="main__article-p">
    <%= recent_article[0].content %>   (Read More...)</span>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I've been trying to figure this out. I did what you said but my `index.ejs` file it still saying `recent_article is undefined`.